# "Request-URI Too Long" in node.js request

Tags: node.js

When trying to download google documents in node.js request module the following is returned

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>414 Request-URI Too Long</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request-URI Too Long</h1>
<p>The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity
limit for this server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

How can this be avoided without reconfiguring Apache?